# GNUPLOT: 2d histogram from set of points

Tags: dictionary, gnuplot, histogram

I have a pairs of the points with their weights:

```
#x  y  w
0.111342 0.478917 0.232487 
0.398107 1.79559 0.221714 
0.200731 2.58651 0.0776068 
0.0967412 1.49904 0.0645355 
6.17638 8.63101 0.715604 
0.306128 3.10917 0.0984595 
0.340707 3.19344 0.10669 
7.18627 8.59859 0.835751 
8.56 9.63894 0.888065 
5.14272 6.86074 0.749587 
0.747202 3.812 0.196013 
8.71891 10.1355 0.860232 
0.346714 1.45895 0.237647 
5.21932 8.84491 0.590094 
9.42138 12.2082 0.771725 
0.215627 2.42317 0.0889856
```

How to plot nice 2d histogram image with color bar?
I found nice [density map](http://pelican.rsvs.ulaval.ca/mediawiki/index.php/Making_density_maps_using_Gnuplot) description but I don't wont to go via python.
I there way to use only gnuplot scripting?

Answer (score 5):

It's best to use an external histogramming tool, but you can achieve something similar in gnuplot via:

```
set pm3d at b      # draw on bottom, not as 3d surface
set view map       # don't do a 3-d looking plot
set dgrid 100,100  # grid of 100x100 pixels
splot 'dat.txt' w pm3d
```

Comment: I should note that this doesn't allow you to use the weights (it just bins the first two columns). For that, you need to use an external histogram tool: I suggest python's numpy "histogram2d" function, or gsl's gsl_histogram2d functions

Comment: can you recommend an external histogramming tool?